# How to handle big object sent on socket java?

Tags: java, json, sockets, gson

I am trying to implement a client-server in java 
and i made connection between in sockets 
and sending JSON objects as strings on streams
if i have big object is there's a way to handle it 
so i don't have to regroup it because the limit size of tcp packet (cant know when the single object is fully transferred to me as client or not yet)
note :am using G-son to convert objects to JSON objects

Comment: You have to write the object in chunks.  Do you happen to have what you've got so far so that we could see how you're serializing your JSON entity?

Comment: @Makoto yes i did already to send a JSON object retrieved from a java object and it worked but it was a small object i need a mechanism to do it for bigger ones maybe ones holding photos (as String) so i assure i get it all as one object not chunks

Comment: You don't have to write your object in chunks. The API will take care of packetising for you. Just write the data. @Makoto is mistaken about this.

Comment: @EJP if thats true whatever the size of object is then my problem is solved .. thnx for answering .. hope u assure me thats true because i read thatit made it to chunks but not sure

Comment: I have already stated that it's true. How many times exactly would you like me to repeat myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there's a way to handle it so i don't have to regroup it because the limit size of tcp packet

You don't have to care about the size of TCP packets. Just write the data. TCP will segmentize and packetize it for you.

> (cant know when the single object is fully transferred to me as client or not yet)

Yes you can. You reach the closing '}', as @StephenC mentions. Your JSON parser should take of that for you in any case.

Your question is founded on false assumptions.

Comment: am not using a JSON parser using a gson which handle parsing for me 
will that do the mission for me ? (whatever the size is)

Comment: You are parsing JSON objects. Ergo you are using a JSON parser. Any competently written parser should behave as described here.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have big object is there's a way to handle it so I don't have to regroup it because the limit size of tcp packet.  (I cant know when the single object is fully transferred to me as client or not yet)

Actually, the client *can* know when it has received a complete JSON object.  When your client sees the `}` that matches the opening `{`, you have the complete object.  Of course, this means that that your client needs to understand JSON syntax, but you can use an off-the-shelf JSON parser to do that.

So the best way to do this is for the server to generate and send the JSON, and the client to parse the socket input stream using a normal JSON parser.  If you do it that way, then you don't need to know whether the TCP/IP stack has broken the data stream into multiple packets.  By the time the JSON parser sees them, they will have been reassembled into a stream of bytes.

---

If this doesn't answer your question, we need to see what your code is currently doing to generate and send the JSON on the server side.

Comment: thanx for answering 
i am using gson to make a json object in server and the opposite in client .. so am not reading json object by my self 
will gson handle that automatically for me ?